# Joomla - Upgrade Version 3.2.3 to 3.4.7

Tags: joomla-3.x, security, upgrade

Recently, we have done Penetration testing for our Joomla site and came across below Vulnerabilities

```
Joomla Core Remote Code Execution Vulnerability
Solution : Upgrade to version 3.4.6
```

Reference: [Core Remote Code Execution Vulnerability](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/12/joomla-remote-code-execution-the-details.html)

AND

```
Web application potentially vulnerable to clickjacking
Solution: Return the X-Frame options HTTP header with the page's response
```

We have outlined some Action Items as below

- Our server meet the minimum technical requirements for Joomla `3.4.7`
  as its already running version `3.2.3`
- List down all third-party extensions in use. This includes
  components, modules, plugins, languages, and templates.
- Determine whether the third-party extensions we rely on are ready for
  the version of Joomla we are migrating to.

Migrating from **2.5** to **3.x** is mini-migration which is already done in our case.

1. How do we go about upgrading from **3.2.3 to 3.4.7** ?
2. How do we upgrade **Database** ?
3. If upgrade is done successfully, how do we test all the
   **components/extensions/modules** ?
4. Any official guidelines available to perform the operation?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: You should take a backup of your site, either manually or using [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html).

---

The upgrade can be done using Joomla's **1 click update feature** in the admin back-end. Go to:

**Components** >> **Joomla! Update** >> **Clear Cache** >> **Find Updates**

This should provide you with an update to the latest version, which I'm just going to say is 3.5.0, not 3.4.7

---

Any changes to the database will be done in the update, so you don't need to worry about that. Basically every Joomla update contains it's own SQL file associated with that version. The SQL file may contain database changes or be blank.

---

Updating from Joomla 3.2.3 to 3.4.8 is considered a minor update so as for compatibility, your extensions should run perfectly fine. There was a change made to the `String` framework package in Joomla 3.5.0 to prevent conflicts with PHP7, so I would suggest updating all extensions to their latest versions too.

---

Hope this helps